# Why is my betta fish starting to have a dull color?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, betta

I have a betta fish that I’ve had for a year now. I’m not exactly sure what kind he is, but I found a picture of him when I first got him and he was a really bright pink/purple, his tail and fins were nice and full, but now his color is duller… About 5 months ago, I came home to half his tail literally missing; I’m not sure if he nipped it off, or it got ripped off but it’s not fin rot since it’s starting to grow back. He’s overall a really happy fish, he eats well, is very active, and has lots of energy… I’m just worried about the color dullness; is that natural because of age, or am I missing something?

For reference - he has a 5 gallon (19 L) tank, a filter, a heater, resting places, hiding places, and plants

I’m open to all feedback. Please help me out, I really want to be a good fish owner :)

Comment: Could you add two images, where the difference is visible? Could you also post the readings of the water in the aquarium?